# OMS to patch Non azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, server

I have servers on Azure and I am using OMS to patch the servers, which is working fine. How ever there are many servers which are non azure like Laptops, Is it possible to patch the Non-Azure VMs from OMS?
Could you please help?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You are more likely to receive an answer if you ask this on Server Fault where this would be on topic.

Comment: What is your laptops OS type? Windows client does not support this, such as Windows 7, 8,10.

Comment: The OS types are Windows 10 and 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to patch the Non-Azure VMs from OMS?

Yes, it is possible. You need install OMS agent on your local VMs.

However, if you want to use `Update management`, there are some prerequisites that you need to be satisfied. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/oms-solution-update-management#prerequisites).

> 1.The solution supports performing update assessments against Windows
>   Server 2008 and higher, and update deployments against Windows Server
>   2012 and higher. Server Core and Nano Server installation options are
>   not supported.
>
> **2.Windows client operating systems are not supported.**
>
> 3.Windows agents must either be configured to communicate with a Windows
>   Server Update Services (WSUS) server or have access to Microsoft
>   Update.

More information about connect Windows computers to OMS please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-windows-agents).